# Excel formula for comparing 2 cells with values

Tags: excel-formula

I need a formula that displays the below, but cannot for the life of me get it to work:

If A1 is not blank, B1 must be 'yes' (I want either a 0 or 100 to be displayed in C1 dependant on result).

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to chain a few functions together. The first is `ISBLANK()` which, as it sounds, tells you if the value provided is blank. As you mentioned, you want the case when it's *not* blank, so you'll need to enclose this in the `NOT()` function, which will reverse the boolean result.

For example, when `B1`'s formula is `=ISBLANK(A1)`, the result is `FALSE` when `A1` is not blank. Since you want it to be `TRUE`, you'll use `=NOT(ISBLANK(A1))`.

To get `B1` to show a value besides `TRUE` or `FALSE` at this point, you can use the `IF()` function, which allows you to specify a value to be shown when the result is `TRUE` and a different value for `FALSE`.

In your case, `=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(A1)),'yes','no')` should give you `yes` when `A1` is not blank, and `no` when `A1` is blank.

You can also utilize the `IF()` function in `C1` to do your additional "0 or 100" logic.

Answer (score 0):

So:

A1
Project one

B1
Yes or No

C1 - if project one, is 'yes' then value to be 100, if project one is 'no' then value to be 0.

Answer (score -1):

You Can Use If Condition.
Formula Is :

```
If(A1=B1,"Match","Not Match")
```

Where A1,B1 Cell Values ,
If Condition Is True Than Match Will Execute Otherwise Not Match Will Execute.

Write This Condition in C1 Cell

Comment: Hi, problem is that the two cells values will change.

Answer (score -2):

Excel Formula:

`=IF(ISBLANK(A1), "No", "Yes")`